# Use of httpResponse django

Tags: django, httpresponse

As far as I can think of, HttpResponse is used for REST application. I cannot figure out any other use of httpresponse. I want to understand other uses of HttpResponse. Help by anyone would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpResponse` is used to send an HTTP response of any kind and can be used for any application, not just a REST app.

I'm sure you've used the `render` function a lot in your views to return a template. Under the hood, it returns an `HttpResponse`. Here's the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/shortcuts/#render).

Another use case is what if you want to send an image or a PDF document from your views? You can't use `render` for that. Here's a example:

```
def pdf_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")

    with open('my_file.pdf', 'rb') as f:
        response.write(f.read())

    return response
```

---

In short, `HttpResponse` can be used to send any kind of data over HTTP. You can use it to set custom headers, or anything you can think of related to HTTP responses.